# What are the details of Adobe AIR file permissions?

Tags: actionscript-3, file-io, air

I need to know what the details are of the file permissions of an ***adobe AIR app***.

Specifically, to where can may it write text files? Anywhere on the local system? I heard Adobe has a set of "*Sandbox Permissions*" but these just confuse me as I don't know where they apply.

Additionally I wish to know if you need some kind of special permission to **append** to a file somewhere on the system.

Any help/opinions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

You can write text files or edit text files pretty much anywhere. The only exception that I know of is the applicationDirectory (the directory where your app is installed), but even then there are methods of getting around this (but it is advised not to mess around in the applicationDirectory). There is no special permission needed to edit a file. Check the above link for appropriate places to write text files (usually applicationStorageDirectory or documentsDirectory).

The one hiccup that I am not really sure about is Windows Vista/7 UAC permissions where you will sometimes need to grant admin access to edit files. I am not sure how AIR handles this (conceivably running the AIR app as admin should work).